# How to use a file within a loop of another file

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to import games into a 'hub' which allows you to both play the games as much as you want, and allows you to choose a new game after finishing. The code is working up to the play again, and I can't figure out why.

I have tried different types of loops, and different ways to import the games, but it is not working. I do not get an error, but it does not run the game again. instead, the code runs the loop, but acts like the game code is not there after the first run. It also will not let you pick a game again after you've played it once.

```
while True:

    print("What game would you like to play?")
    print("")
    print("(please only type in a number)")
    Ghoice = int(input("We have: \n 1. Rock Paper Scissors \n 2. Hangman \n 3. Guess the number \n 4. Two player Tic Tac Toe"))

    if Ghoice == 1:

        import ROCK_PAPER_SCISSORS
        while True:
            ROCK_PAPER_SCISSORS.RPS
            if input("Play again? (type y or n)") != "y" or "Y":
                break

    if input("Do you want to play another game? (type y or n)") in ["n", "N"]:
        break
```

Note: I have more code after the first choice, but it is the same type of code as the if statement, so I didn't think it was important to show.
Here's the code for the game I'm referencing:

```
from random import randint

def RPS():
    player = input("Rock (r), Paper (p), or Scissors (s)?")
    chosen = randint(1,3)
    if chosen == 1:
        comp = 'r'
    elif chosen == 2:
        comp = 'p'
    else:
        comp = 's'

    print(player , 'vs.' , comp)

    if player == comp:
        print('DRAW!')
    elif player == 'r' and comp == 's':
        print('Player wins!')
    elif player == 'p' and comp == 'r':
        print('Player Wins!')
    elif player == 'r' and comp == 'p':
        print('Computer Wins!')
    elif player == 'p' and comp == 's':
        print('Computer Wins!')
    elif player == 's' and comp == 'p':
        print('Player Wins!')
    elif player == 's' and comp == 'r':
        print('Computer Wins!')
    else:
        print('You either typed a capital version of one of the letters,')
        print('Or an incorrect choice. either way, you gotta try again.')

RPS()
```

Comment: For the future: Questions about python code should get the 'python' tag.  Editor/IDE tags should only be used if the question is about the behavior of the editor/IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first off, `again` isn't defined when you test it at the bottom.

Second, this line:

```
if input("Play again? (type y or n)") != "y" or "Y":
```

Will not do what you think it does. It isn't checking if the input is equal to "y", or if it's equal to "Y". Rather it checks if the input is equal to "y", and if it isn't, it evaluates "Y", which is truthy. You probably want something like this:

```
while True:

    print("What game would you like to play?")
    print("")
    print("(please only type in a number)")
    Ghoice = int(input("We have: \n 1. Rock Paper Scissors \n 2. Hangman \n 3. Guess the number \n 4. Two player Tic Tac Toe"))

    if Ghoice == 1:
        import ROCK_PAPER_SCISSORS
        while True:
            ROCK_PAPER_SCISSORS.RPS
            if input("Play again? (type y or n)") not in ["y", "Y"]:
                break
    # Code for other choices
    if input("Do you want to play another game? (type y or n)") in ["n", "N"]:
        break
```

Now, you are relying on the game code to run at module load time--but that will only happen once, regardless of how many times the `import` statement is executed. To fix that, you'll want to replace the last line of your game code with

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    RPS()
```

That will ensure that nothing runs automatically when the module is loaded, but you will be able to run the game as a separate program if you want. Then, you'll want to replace

```
...
while True:
    ROCK_PAPER_SCISSORS.RPS
    ...
```

with

```
...
while True:
    ROCK_PAPER_SCISSORS.RPS()
    ...
```

to actually run the game code on each iteration of the while loop.

Comment: @Mikaekae I'd have to see the source for that module to know for sure. You aren't actually calling any functions on the imported module, though, so I suspect the problem is that you are relying on code execution on module load to run the game--but that only happens once per program invocation, no matter how many times you run the "import" statement.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I completely forgot about showing the game's code as well as the Hub. I will fix that right away.

Comment: @Mikaekae Well, the problem is pretty much what I expected. I have updated my answer to address that in light of more information about the code.